# What is the best way to handle transaction across SQL Servers in C#.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project where I need to transfer the old data from production server to archive server. Here I have a problem dealing with data consistency across servers if there is any failure in the middle of transfer. It's nothing but implementing the transaction.

Whenever there is a system failure during the data transfer, the process should delete all the transferred records from archive server and start the whole transfer process as fresh when the system is back.

Note: I can't use distributed transactions to achieve due to some permissions/settings reasons at my client's premises.

Is there any way to handle this either in C#.net or SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Could you explain why you need to do this using C#? Use the SQL Server features; that's faster and less work.

Comment: SQL server is also fine for me.But how to achieve this using sql server across servers?

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services

Comment: Don't do this using C#. Use the [SQL Server Integration Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)

Comment: where is the transaction related topic here in this above link?

Comment: It is not there. You will have to learn SSIS. At the bottom of the Wiki article there are several links to official sites and to examples.

Comment: do you try to modify data in production server,ex: delete old data, or just read?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is used to 'roll back' to before a database was edited when any part of the entire transaction fails. You could try to modify it to suite your needs.

(first reference the System.Transactions-namespace)

```
    System.Transactions

    using(TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            //modify your database here

            transaction.Complete();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: will this handle across the servers?

Comment: I honestly do not know. I thought I'd leave it to you to find out. Please let me know if works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE  @TranCounter INT; 

    SET @TranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT; 

    IF @TranCounter > 0 
      SAVE TRANSACTION savepointrb1; 
    ELSE 
      BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

   BEGIN TRY

       -- your code will be here. if you are using multiple stored procedures then                
          apply this code on that

       IF @TranCounter = 0 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     

    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH 
      IF @TranCounter = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
      ELSE 
        IF Xact_state() <> -1 
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION savepointrb1; 

        END CATCH
```